# Laravel generate subqueries with eloquent

Tags: laravel-7

I want to generate a SQL query like below:

```
select *
from ocs
where ocs.wfx_oc_no = 'OC11' and
ocs.id in (select id
          from buyers
          where buyers.buyer_code = 'B01')
```

Can someone help me as to how to do this with laravel subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$data =  OCS::where('wfc_oc_no','OC11')->where('id', Buyers::where('buyer_code','B01')->first())->get();

Comment: This will make multiple DB calls whereas a sub-query does it once. In my case, there are a lot of whereIn clauses. This was not the answer I expected. Anyway, it gave me an insight into what I am doing right now. Thanks for your input.

Comment: This can be used to get the job done so I am marking this as the answer. Anyway, I expected something based on sub-queries.

Comment: Thanks i'll try next time give best answer